# error with AIDE

Tags: android, tablet

In case of creation of the blank project in AIDE on a pad 4.2.2 of the basic code, AIDE finds an error:

> This method must return the value of type"

Also QuickFix suggest to correct it by 'return 0' adding before a penultimate bracket that in turn attracts besides an error

> A void method can't return a value

Also suggests to remove digit 0. Application is compiled, but not launched, referring to an error in application...Any ideas, why is it so? AIDE versions I tried the different.

Comment: Now I tried to install AIDE on smartphone with 4.2.2 and it works fine! No errors with new project, no error with running app! My tablet is Wexler Tab7t. Somebody help! :-(

Comment: Question is closed. One more downloaded version is work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and when i reinstalled the app it worked. Also make sure you dont have a patched apk. I had that error with a pirate patched apk. I installed the original app with the premium key apk. XD Hope this helps you!